# Session data gone after redirect in CI

Tags: codeigniter, session

i need your help.
I used the session to record the user selected business type in CI. For example,$this->ci->session->set_userdata('biztype','food'). When user login,it works ok. However, once the user logout, session will be destroyed in the function logout().So i set the userdata again in the function logout().You can view the code below:

```
function logout()
{
  $biztype = $this->ci->session->userdata('biztype');
  $this->delete_autologin();

  $this->ci->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => '', 'username' => '', 'status' =>  ''));

  $this->ci->session->sess_destroy();
  $this->ci->session->set_userdata('biztype',$biztype);
  //echo $this->ci->session->userdata('biztype');   //here, i can get biztype that i want
}
```

However,when i logout and redirect to homepage, i cant get the userdata('biztype') and my session_id have changed.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, i am trying to get the point. You log out a user but keep it's biztype after redirection to the homepage to use for what?

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from CodeIgniter User Guide:

> **Destroying a Session**
>
> To clear the current session:
>
> ```
> $this->session->sess_destroy();
> ```
>
> Note: This function should be the last one called, and even flash
>   variables will no longer be available. If you only want some items
>   destroyed and not all, use unset_userdata().

So no, you cannot destroy a session then add user_data to it, you need to reload / redirect then once the NEW session is established add data.

Try using cookies for peristance, or use the mentioned `unset_userdata()` fn.

Comment: You mean when I destroy session, the session is no longer record data, so i cant add data any more. But i can add data when the page reload/redirect,because the NEW session is established at this time?

Comment: Don't forget you are not just doing PHP programming you are playing within the boundaries of CI. And CI does not allow you to destroy a session then add stuff to it.  They recommend you destroy last.  There are other things working in the background you might not know about!

Comment: Jakup is correct, however for the sake of  logic, after logout, you should not "unset" user data in accordance to just try to make code work. Can you explain a little bit, where this "biztype" var will be used at home page after redirection? OR Do you try using set_flash data?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->session->sess_destroy() ;`

This function should be called only at the end of the execution. For unsetting data (as you're trying to do) it's better to use `unset_userdata` method. See how you should implement that:

```
$unset_items = array('user_id' => '', 'username' => '', 'status' =>  '') ;

$this->ci->session->unset_userdata( $unset_items ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $email  = "abc@gmail.com";

   ///set the session 
   use the set_userdata function and include the session library

   $this->load->library('session');

   $this->session->set_userdata('session name',Value);
   i.e.
   $this->session->set_userdata('email', $email);

   //unset the session 
   $this->session->unset_userdata('session name');
   i.e.
   $this->session->unset_userdata('email');
```